# How can I ggplot a merged data frame composed of factors with an alphabetical sorted x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have two data frames of nations A and B, some are matching. With `rbind()` and `dplyr::summarise()` I generate a new data frame with the counts of each country. In order to `ggplot()` with alphabetically sorted x-axis I sort the data frame by country with `order()` and even drop the rownames. Why are in the resulting plot some of the merged countries still appearing at the end of the x-axis and not in the desired alphabetic sorting I've made? (BTW isn't the order of a data frame alphabetic by default, even when it is merged?) Thanks for your help.

```
# Group A
ctry <- factor(c("ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "BEL", "BIH", "CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "CHE", 
                 "DEU", "DEU", "ITA", "KOS", "KOS", "KOS", "SVK", "TUR", "TUR"))
df01 <- data.frame(ctry)

rm(ctry)

# Group B
ctry <- factor(c("ECU", "GHA", "CHE", "JAM", "ITA", "KOS", "TUR", "DOM"))
df02 <- data.frame(ctry)

# Group joined
df <- rbind(df01, df02)

# Countries Counts 

library(dplyr)

df.sum <- df %>%
  group_by(ctry) %>%
  summarise(num=n()) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

# alphabetic sorting

df.sum  <- df.sum [order(df.sum [1]),]
rownames(df.sum ) <- NULL

df.sum 

# ctry num                         # Here it's alphabetically sorted...
# 1   ALB   4
# 2   BEL   1
# 3   BIH   1
# 4   CHE   8
# 5   DEU   2
# 6   DOM   1
# 7   ECU   1
# 8   GHA   1
# 9   ITA   2
# 10  JAM   1
# 11  KOS   4
# 12  SVK   1
# 13  TUR   3

# ggplot                         # ...but not in the ggplot. -->

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df.sum , aes(ctry)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = num, fill = ctry)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Countries")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factors are just numbers with labels, so they may not combine like you think they should.  With `rbind` and `c` you get df01 countries first and then anything *new* in df02.

```
unclass(ctry)
[1] 3 4 1 6 5 7 8 2
attr(,"levels")
[1] "CHE" "DOM" "ECU" "GHA" "ITA" "JAM" "KOS" "TUR"
```

I would use `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `rbind` and that will tell you one problem and try to correct it.

```
df2 <- bind_rows(df01, df02)
 Warning message:
 In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
```

Then `ctry` is just a character string and will sort like you want

```
  df.sum <- df2 %>%
  group_by(ctry) %>%
  summarise(num=n())

  ggplot...
```